# Kernel.--/2 weird behaviour

Tags: elixir

Consider the following code:

```rb
iex|1 ▶ [:foo, :bar] -- [:foo, :bar]
#⇒ []
```

So far, so good. But:

```rb
iex|2 ▶ [:foo, :bar] -- [] -- [:foo, :bar]
#⇒ [:foo, :bar]
```

Even more, it’s not about right-to-left:

```rb
iex|3 ▶ [:foo, :bar] -- [:foo] -- [:foo, :bar] 
#⇒ [:foo, :bar]

iex|4 ▶ IO.inspect([:foo, :bar], label: "1") --
...|4 ▶   IO.inspect([:foo], label: "2") --
...|4 ▶   IO.inspect([:foo, :bar], label: "3")
#⇒ 1: [:foo, :bar]
#  2: [:foo]
#  3: [:foo, :bar]

#⇒ [:foo, :bar]
```

Am I missing something obvious? What’s going on here? There should not be any magic, since [`Kernel.--/2`](https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/blob/v1.8.1/lib/elixir/lib/kernel.ex#L1324) is simply delegating to `:erlang.--(left, right)`.

Why consecutive subtracting lists results in noop?

---

FWIW, with parentheses everything works as expected:

```rb
iex|5 ▶ ([:foo, :bar] -- [:foo]) -- [:foo, :bar]
#⇒ []
```

---

More fun:

```rb
iex|6 ▶ [:foo, :bar] -- [:foo] -- []  
#⇒ [:bar]
iex|7 ▶ [:foo, :bar] -- [:foo] -- [:foo]
#⇒ [:foo, :bar]
iex|8 ▶ [:foo, :bar] -- [:foo] -- [:bar]
#⇒ [:bar]
```

---

*Follow-up findings.* Short-form reducing somehow manages to follow right-associative semantics:

```rb
Enum.reduce([[:foo, :bar], [:foo], [:foo, :bar]], &Kernel.--/2)
#⇒ [:foo, :bar]
```

But the full well-formed one with an explicit function *does not*

```rb
Enum.reduce(
  [[:foo, :bar], [:foo], [:foo, :bar]],
  fn e, acc -> acc -- e end
)
#⇒ []
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`++` and `--` are [right-associative operations](https://learnyousomeerlang.com/starting-out-for-real#lists). Your initial code:

```
[:foo, :bar] -- [:foo] -- [:foo, :bar]
```

Is actually evaluated as

```
[:foo, :bar] -- ([:foo] -- [:foo, :bar])
```

When you take what's in the brackets: you remove a list of elements from `[:foo]`, and the list you remove contains the original list (`[:foo]`) thus evaluates to an empty list `[]`.

Then you remove this empty list from the leftmost list:

```
[:foo, :bar] -- []
```

Which leaves you with the result `[:foo, :bar]`.

Comment: Thank you! I am still a bit struggled to understand how `Enum.reduce([[:foo, :bar], [:foo], [:foo, :bar]], &Kernel.--/2) #⇒ [:foo, :bar]` manages to follow right-associative semantics (the full well-formed `Enum.reduce([[:foo, :bar], [:foo], [:foo, :bar]], fn e, acc -> acc -- e end)` _does not_, it returns an empty list.

Comment: The difference comes from how the `Kernel.--/2` call handles it's param order. In your case, `acc` will be the first element of the main array at the first call (`[:foo, :bar]`), and `e` is the second. Inside the reduce function: When it comes to the Kernel call it will evaluate to `e -- acc` (i.e.. `[:foo] -- [:foo, :bar]`) whereas in your own inline function its `acc -- e`. Different order of params. If you put a simple debug line with `IO.puts(inspect {e, acc})` in your inline function(s) you can see how it plays out at each step.

Comment: Yes, thanks again, now I think I have a complete understanding.

Answer (score 0):

At `Enum.reduce([[:foo, :bar], [:foo], [:foo, :bar]], fn e, acc -> acc -- e end)`, you wont have the same problems that with `[:foo, :bar] -- [:foo] -- [:foo, :bar]` that is because you will operate over each element not over all of them at the same time.

As `acc` will start at `[]`, so with with each element you will have:

#1 => [] -- [:foo, :bar] = []

#2 => [] -- [:foo] = []

#3 => [] -- [:foo, :bar] = []

So you will have an empty list at end.

Comment: This is not a problem, it turned out this is the desired well-documented behaviour. Also, how does this answer explains `Enum.reduce([[:foo, :bar], [:foo], [:foo, :bar]], &Kernel.--/2)` case?

Comment: Also, the `acc` will start with `[:foo, :bar]`, not with `[]`.

Comment: I see my bad on answer sorry about. I think the confusing is related to how the arguments are passed to the  `&Kernel.--/2` function. When using `fn e, acc -> acc -- e end` we are giving them a different order that when using `&Kernel.--/2` that the long representation will be `fn (e, acc) -> e -- acc end`